# tkinter: multiple checkboxes ticked at once

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make settings menu, but once I press one radio button or checkbox, everything presses at at once too, what to do? most answers said that it's because lack of variable setting, but doesn't seem to be the case, replaced array with separate values, but it is far less convenient and seems to be bad practice, is there a way to do it using array?

```
    def open_settings(self,root):
         #lango nustatymai
         self.settings = Toplevel(root)
         self.settings.title("Nustatymai")
         self.settings.geometry("210x230")
         #elementu sukurimas
         mode_frame = LabelFrame(self.settings, text = 'Nustatymai')
         settings_label = Label(self.settings,
                                text = "Nustatymai",
                                fg = "blue",
                                width = 30, height =1,
                                bg = "grey")
         c_label = Label(self.settings, text = "C#")
         java_label = Label(self.settings, text = "Java")
         python_label = Label(self.settings, text = "Python")
         predetermined_label = Label (self.settings, text = "Iš anksto\n nustatyta\n salyga")
         cyclic_label = Label(self.settings, text = "Rezultatai\n salygoje")
         save_button = Button(self.settings, text = "Išsaugoti", command = self.create_json)
         close_button = Button(self.settings, text = "Uždaryti", command = self.close_win)
         #pasirinkimo sukurimas
         correction_mode = Radiobutton(mode_frame,
                                      text = "Taisymas",
                                      variable = self.mode,
                                      value = 0).pack()
         analysis_mode = Radiobutton(mode_frame,
                                     text = "Analizė",
                                     variable = self.mode,
                                     value= 1).pack()

         #checkbox nustatymu
         for i in range(3):
             self.predetermined_buttons.append(Checkbutton(self.settings,
                                               variable = self.predetermined_values[i],
                                               onvalue = True,
                                               offvalue = False))
             self.cyclic_buttons.append(Checkbutton(self.settings,
                                        variable = self.cyclic_values[i],
                                        onvalue = True,
                                        offvalue = False))
```

##### Edit

Declaration of variables:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kvargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kvargs)
        if os.path.exists("conf.txt"):
            self.load_json()
        else:
            self.mode = 1
            self.predetermined_values = [True,True,True]
            self.cyclic_values = [True,True,True]
        self.predetermined_buttons = []
        self.cyclic_buttons = []
```

Comment: The code you present doesn't show the definition of `predetermined_values` or `cyclic_values`. The problem may be there.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. It's unreadable that way. Instead, [edit] your question to include the added information (and delete the unreadable comment).

Comment: sorry, I'm new around here, edited the question

Comment: `self.cyclic_values` needs to be a list of Tkinter variables if you're going to use them as the `variable=` option of a `Checkbutton` (**not** a list of boolean values). See [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and [The Tkinter Checkbutton Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111212955id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm).